# Regex to verify image files without special characters?

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that validates only files that are of type .jpg, .png or .gif and do consist of letters, numbers, dashes, and underscores only.

This is what I've got so far:

```
/\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[\w-]+\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$/igm
```

`\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`